Do I require a flyback diode across this fan connector to prevent inductive reverse voltage?
I have the following schematic. A 5v DC fan is connected such that the 5v is connected to the positive terminal and the the ground connection is conencted to the drain of the Nchannel MOSFET. The N-Channel MOSFET being controlled by a GPIO pin from a microcontroller. When the GPIO pin goes high then the MOSFET pulls the ground pin of the FAN to ground and hence the FAN turns on.The MOSFET has its own flyback diode. My question is do I require a flyback diode across the connector of the fan? or does the diode from the N-Channel MOSFET suffice ?

Edit 1: I have added a flyback diode across the terminals of the FAN. I chose the MBR120LSF which is  a schottky diode with 20V, 1A.
.

What do you mean by "the MOSFET has its own flyback diode"? Do you mean there's a zener/TVS in antiparallel with it? Or that the MOSFET is avalanche rated (the Si2302 shown is not)? Just putting a regular diode in antiparallel with a MOSFET will do nothing.

Also, what is the pinout of that fan? I'm not familiar with any five-pin standard fan connectors. Are you sure it won't be a problem to have those two pins permanently grounded while you switch the other ground pin? The fan shown in the image has only two wires, so that evidently isn't the fan in question.

As noted, the MOSFET body diode does not protect against any inductive transient here, since the polarity of the transient is positive at the MOSFET drain terminal.

A flyback diode is connected across the inductive load, not across the transistor, so the body diode in the MOSFET can't work as a flyback diode (If the MOSFET is avalanche-rated, the body diode does work as a clamp and does help, otherwise no).

@Hearth The conenctor is a 3 pin connector. Pins 4 and 5 are the side pins of the connector that attach the conentor to the PCB. Thats the issue from our Library for these types of connectors. Theres about 3 dozen connectors with this wierd pinning(Before my time.), and I am too bogged down with other things to change them.

Thank you @Hearth @ 比尔盖子 > Yes it was a body diode not a flyback diode pointed out as Andy aka. I mixed up the names. Yes I will use a diode across the terminals of the connector.


or does the diode from the N-Channel MOSFET suffice ?

The MOSFET doesn't have a flyback diode. It has a body diode and that won't protect the MOSFET from inductive back-emfs coming from a fan in the drain circuit.

do I require a flyback diode across the connector of the fan?

Normally you would do this.

yes, body diode. I was too focused on the flyback diode, that I forgot the name of the body diode. I will add the Flyback diode to my design.

i am guessing a fast switching diode like a schottky shoulf work for this setup ?

@EmeraldMonk it needn't be a fast switching diode at all. Just an ordinary diode rated for the flyback current will do. All diodes go from reverse blocking to forward conduction without suffering delay. It's the other way that slow-ish diodes suffer i.e. they don't go from a conducting state to a blocking state so quickly (even when the voltage has reversed).

@EmeraldMonk A schottky actually makes for a pretty bad flyback diode; the lower voltage across it makes the load take longer to turn off. (This is more of a problem for relays, where opening slowly causes damage.)

@Hearth, do you have any examples of a diode that might be favourable to use in this case ?

@EmeraldMonk I'll step in here... what is the maximum peak (including stall and start-up) current of the fan or any other load you might connect?

@Andyaka, when I connect the Fan to a 5V supply, the fan has a startup current of 80mA, and then swings between 70 - 80mA when its runs continuously. I must note, that the plan is to drive the Fan using a PWM signal from the microcontroller. If this doesnt work, then its a constant high signal.

@EmeraldMonk Virtually any diode will do. Choose a non-Schottky as mentioned by Hearth. Default choice would be 1N400x series.

@EmeraldMonk If you want to turn the load off fast, a standard diode plus a zener is the usual arrangement. But like I said, it's not as critical to this application, as the fan doesn't need to turn off quickly.
